# Moonshine 2.2.0 compilation error for Royale Browser Project

Tags: apache-royale

I have just downloaded to use Moonshine to compile a Moonshine generate NewJavaScriptBrowserProject and got the following error. All compilation works for NewActionScriptProject, NewFlexBrowserProject, NewFlexDesktopProject except NewJavaScriptBrowserProject. The error is Error: Invalid version specified, '0.0.0' for playerglobal.swc. My installed version is 11.1. Please advise resolution. Thanks.

```
: Moonshine IDE™ 2.2.0
: Copyright © Prominic.NET, Inc. All rights reserved.
: Source code is under Apache License, Version 2.0
: https://github.com/prominic/Moonshine-IDE
: Uses as3abc (LGPL), as3swf (MIT), fzip (ZLIB), asblocks (Apache License 2.0), NativeApplicationUpdater (LGPL)
: Running on Adobe AIR 32.0.0.125
: Compiling NewJavaScriptBrowserProject
: Using Royale Compiler codebase: "D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs"
: Using Royale SDK: "D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs"
: MXMLJSC
: -sdk-js-lib=D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs\frameworks\js\Royale\generated-sources
: -load-config+=obj/NewJavaScriptBrowserProjectConfig.xml
: -compiler.targets=JSRoyale
: -js-output=D:\WorkspaceMoonshine\NewJavaScriptBrowserProject
: Error: Invalid version specified, '0.0.0'.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have created new Royale project using Jewel Template, you need to use newest [Nightly build](http://apacheroyaleci.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com:8080/job/royale-asjs_jsonly/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/out/) of Royale, because this template is compatible only with version 0.9.6 which wasn't released yet.
Go to the project **Settings** -> **Build options** and setup that SDK for your project.

[image]

Comment: Have downloaded ver 0.9.6 and setup this SDK using the Setting->Build options in Moonshine 2.2.0, created a new Royale Browser Project and selected Template Type as Royale Browser Project Jewel. But still giving the same error ie Error: Invalid version specified, '0.0.0' after compilation. Please advise resolution. Am using Windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide me full console output from your latest attempt with Royale 0.9.6.

Comment: Here is the full console output Part 1 (because of stackoverflow limits to add comment:
: Moonshine IDE™ 2.2.0
: Copyright © Prominic.NET, Inc. All rights reserved.
: Source code is under Apache License, Version 2.0
: https://github.com/prominic/Moonshine-IDE
: Uses as3abc (LGPL), as3swf (MIT), fzip (ZLIB), asblocks (Apache License 2.0), NativeApplicationUpdater (LGPL)
: Running on Adobe AIR 32.0.0.125
: Compiling NewJavaScriptBrowserProject

Comment: Here is the full console output Part 2
: Using Royale Compiler codebase: "D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs"
: Using Royale SDK: "D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs"
: MXMLJSC
: -sdk-js-lib=D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs\frameworks\js\Royale\generated-sources
: -load-config+=obj/NewJavaScriptBrowserProjectConfig.xml
: -compiler.targets=JSRoyale
: -js-output=D:\WorkspaceMoonshine\NewJavaScriptBrowserProject
: Error: Invalid version specified, '0.0.0'.

Comment: Here is the full console output Part 3
: 
: 
: 
: D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs\frameworks\royale-config.xml(74): col: 0 Error: unable to open 'D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs\frameworks\libs\player\0.0\playerglobal.swc'.
: D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs\frameworks\royale-config.xml (line: 74)
: 
:       </external-library-path>

Comment: Here is the full console output Part 4 :
: D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs\frameworks\royale-config.xml(98): col: 0 Error: unable to open 'D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs\frameworks\libs\player\0.0'.
: D:\Apps\Installations\apache-royale-0.9.4-bin-js\royale-asjs\frameworks\royale-config.xml (line: 98)
: 
:       </library-path>
: 
: 
: 0.7306567 seconds

Comment: Resolved. I have changed the SDK 0.9.4 to 0.9.6 to this project and compilation works now. Thanks.